# Is Admob supported in Middle-East countries?

Tags: ios, admob, iad

I had iAds integrated in my iOS app, my app customers are primarily based out of Middle-East. As it turns out that iAds doesn't support Middle-East countries, so i'm not getting any revenue through iAds. 
I was figuring out whats other alternative for Ads network for iOS in Middle-East, I came across Admob and LeadBolt are the best ones. 
Could you please tell me whether Admob is supported in Middle-East countries?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. And if you integrate Admob you can use it to mediate between a number of other ad networks to further boost your revenue.

Comment: Sorry only about 2% of my traffic comes from the ME so it's not something I focus on but here is the out of the box list of networks available and you can always use the custom adapter to integrate ANY network that you find usefull: AdMob House Ads,
AdMob,
Adfonic,
Hunt Mobile Ads,
InMobi,
Jumptap,
LG U+AD,
MdotM,
Millennial Media,
MobFox,
Pontiflex,
TapIt,
i-mobile

Comment: Thanks, as of now, i have decided to go with Adfonic and InMobi along with Admob. Thanks again for your help, cheers.

Comment: hey @satish, any luck with other ad network than adMob in the middle east??